# Material design switch cross browser issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, internet-explorer-11, material-design

I'm trying to create a material design style switch as demonstrated by Kai Waddington on codepen: http://codepen.io/waddington/pen/BfjiL and below; which works well with activation both on handle and on the switch box, by combination of label and checkbox use.

However, the handle only displays in Chrome and not IE or Firefox. I'm not sure why, and am trying to work out how the code needs to change to work in IE/Firefox while retaining the activation features and remaining as purely html and CSS.

The activation by track or handle and without js ensures it works for mouse, touch, pen etc without too much over complication, so I would like to maintain that.

```css
.label {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #303f9f;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 30px #4a4a4a;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: block;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in 0s;
}
#switch {
  top: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
}
#switch:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -23px;
  left: -75px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  background: #303f9f;
  border: none;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 40px #5f5f5f, 0 0 5px 0 #000;
  transition: box-shadow 500ms ease-in 0s, left 300ms ease-in 0s;
}
#switch:checked:before {
  left: 90px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #303f9f, 0 0 5px 0 #000;
}
#switch:checked + label {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #4a4a4a;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" />
<label for="switch" class="label"></label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem here is that Internet Explorer and Firefox don't consider input controls as having any content (since the input element's content model is *empty*, per the spec), and as such, you cannot place anything *before or after*, hence, no content appearing via your pseudo elements.

You could still accomplish the same effect using a label, and the label's pseudo-elements:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="switch" />
<label for="switch"></label>
```

Next, hide the input, and style the label, as well as the label's `::before` element:

```css
label {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5em;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F00;
    width: 15em; height: 5em;
    transition: background 1s;
}

label::before {
    content: "";
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transition: left 1s;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #F66;
    top: -.25em; left: -.25em;
    width: 5.5em; height: 5.5em;
}

input {
    display: none;
}
```

Lasty, we'll use the `:checked` pseudo class, and `+` adjacent sibling selector to re-style the label and its pseudo-element anytime the checkbox is in the checked state:

```css
input:checked + label {
    background: #900;
}

input:checked + label::before {
    left: 9.75em;
}
```

The end-result appears to be the effect you're after:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/okfaf61x/4/

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, and is simpler in terms of positioning and layout than orignal